# List all the elements from wp_list_pluck

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to list all the elements from `wp_list_pluck()` function, currently, it's showing `only 10 items`, which is set in the WordPress reading settings.

Here is my code,

```
<?php

    $tag_id = get_queried_object()->slug;

    $args = array(
        'product_cat'       => $tag_id,
        'posts_per_page'    => -1
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

            $query->the_post();

            $filtered_posts = $wp_query -> posts;
            $filtered_post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $filtered_posts, 'ID' );
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Here, `$filtered_post_ids` is having `only 10 items`, I want it to have all the items available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you print_r what you are getting?

Comment: I found it, actually I did a mistake in this line, 
$filtered_posts = $wp_query -> posts;

it should be, $filtered_posts = $query -> posts;

Comment: Please read documention of wp_list_pluck() https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck

Comment: Thanks Gufran for your quick response.